# Starting from generating function of Legendre polynomials prove that: $\int_{-1}^{1}xP_n(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx=\frac{2n}{4n^2-1},n=1,2,3,\cdots$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Write the generating function for Legendre's Polynomials. Starting from generating function prove that:
$$(2n+1)P_{n}(x)=P'_{n+1}(x)-P'_{n-1}(x),$$ and hence prove $\int_{-1}^{1}xP_n(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx=\frac{2n}{4n^2-1},n=1,2,3,\cdots$

(Here, $P_n(x)$ denotes  Legendre  Polynomial of degree $n$)

I tried solving this as:

First of all, the generating function $G(x,t)$ for the Legendre's Polynomials $P_n(x)$ (of degree $n$) is given by $(1-2xt+t^2)^{-\frac 12}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^n.$

Differeniating $G$ wrt $x$ we obtain, $t(1-2xt+t^2)^{-\frac 32}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P'_n(x)t^n\tag 1.$

Differeniating $G$ wrt $t$ we obtain, $(1-2xt+t^2)^{-\frac 32}(x-t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)nt^{n-1}\tag 2.$

Multiplying $(2)$ by $t$ we have, $$t(1-2xt+t^2)^{-\frac 32}(x-t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)nt^{n}.$$ Using $(1)$ we can rewrite this equation as, $$x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P'_n(x)t^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P'_n(x)t^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)nt^{n}.$$

---

However, I am unable to proceed further. I am stuck here. I need some  help regarding how to proceed further.

After @Gonçalo's suggestion, i found an answer to the proof of, $$(2n+1)P_{n}(x)=P'_{n+1}(x)-P'_{n-1}(x).$$ But then  again, I find no way, to prove the final assertion that, $$\int_{-1}^{1}xP_n(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx=\frac{2n}{4n^2-1},n=1,2,3,\cdots$$ using $$(2n+1)P_{n}(x)=P'_{n+1}(x)-P'_{n-1}(x)$$ and $$x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P'_n(x)t^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P'_n(x)t^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)nt^{n}.$$

Comment: @Gonçalo That answers this, only partially. But then, what about the 2nd part?